# An upper bound for $\displaystyle\prod_{p \leq n, p \text{ prime }}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1}$

Tags: number-theory

I have been trying to get a proof of the infinitude of the prime numbers by using the algorithm of the Eratosthenes sieve and came up with the following question.

Can I find an upper bound for the following product?
$$\prod_{p \leq n, p \text{ prime}} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1}$$
Numerical computation suggests that $\displaystyle 2\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ works as an upper bound of the product, but I can't prove it. I'd appreciate a lot if anyone provides any help on this.

Comment: Why do you want an *upper* bound?  To show something gets large you want a *lower* bound that more easily is shown to get large.  Being bounded above by something that diverges is not going to help.

Comment: This is the third theorem of Mertens. If you just want an upper bound, you can get it by applying Abelian partial summation to Mertens' first theorem, for which there is a very easy proof.

Comment: By the Eratosthenes sieve, $n\prod_{p \leq \sqrt{n}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$ is a lower bound of $\pi(n)$ which is bounded below by $n\prod_{p \leq n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$. If $2(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})$ is an upper bound of the product, $\pi(n)$ can be bounded below by an expression of the form $\frac{n}{K\log n}$ for some constant $K$.